# How to add cv2.VideoCapture in the PYQT app? pass the scanned barcode data to the app

Tags: python, qt, opencv, pyqt5

I wrote a code to read barcodes from the USB webcam and an application in the PYQT5, but I don't know how to pass a value from a read barcode to the serial number window in my app main panel.

Could anyone suggest something, please?

Camera autodetect barcode and print in it in a console:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import time

def decoder(image):
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(image,0)
    barcode = decode(gray_img)

    for obj in barcode:
        points = obj.polygon
        (x,y,w,h) = obj.rect
        pts = np.array(points, np.int32)
        pts = pts.reshape((-1, 1, 2))
        cv2.polylines(image, [pts], True, (0, 255, 0), 3)

        barcodeData = obj.data.decode("utf-8")
        barcodeType = obj.type
        string = "Data " + str(barcodeData) + " | Type " + str(barcodeType)
        
        cv2.putText(frame, string, (x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.8,(25,20,300), 2)
        if barcodeData not in used_codes:
                print("Barcode: "+barcodeData)
                used_codes.append(barcodeData)
                time.sleep(3)
        else:
                print('This code was aqlready used')
                time.sleep(3)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
used_codes = []
img_counter = 0

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    decoder(frame)
    cv2.imshow('Image', frame)
    code = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if code == ord('q'):
        break
    elif code == ord(' '):
        # SPACE pressed
        img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        print("{} written!".format(img_name))
        img_counter += 1
```

Simple panel to read and later save results:

```
# importing libraries
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import time


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Python ")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 600)
        # calling method
        self.UiComponents()
        # showing all the widgets
        self.show()

    # method for widgets
    def UiComponents(self):

        # creating a radio button
        self.radio_button_fail = QRadioButton(self)
        self.radio_button_pass = QRadioButton(self)
        self.text_batch = QTextEdit(self)
        self.text_sn = QTextEdit(self)
        self.text_problem = QTextEdit(self)
        self.label1 = QLabel(self)
        self.label2 = QLabel(self)
        self.label3 = QLabel(self)
        self.label4 = QLabel(self)
        self.button_save = QPushButton(self)

        self.radio_button_fail.setGeometry(450, 170, 82, 17)
        self.radio_button_pass.setGeometry(450, 140, 82, 17)
        self.text_batch.setGeometry(80, 140, 101, 41)
        self.text_sn.setGeometry(250, 140, 131, 41)
        self.text_problem.setGeometry(550, 140, 200, 41)
        self.label1.setGeometry(110, 100, 101, 41)
        self.label2.setGeometry(260, 100, 130, 41)
        self.label3.setGeometry(450, 100, 101, 41)
        self.label4.setGeometry(570, 100, 170, 41)
        self.button_save.setGeometry(780, 140, 70, 41)
        
        self.label1.setText("Batch")
        self.label2.setText("Serial number")
        self.label3.setText("Status")
        self.label4.setText("Problem description")
        self.button_save.setText("Save")
                                    
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label1.setFont(font)
        self.label2.setFont(font)
        self.label3.setFont(font)
        self.label4.setFont(font)
    
        self.radio_button_fail.setText("FAIL")
        self.radio_button_pass.setText("PASS")
        self.radio_button_pass.setChecked(True)
        self.text_problem.setDisabled(True)


        # setting callable method to radio button
        self.radio_button_fail.clicked.connect(self.check)
        self.radio_button_pass.clicked.connect(self.check)

    # method called by radio button
    def check(self):
            
        # checking if it is checked
        if self.radio_button_fail.isChecked():
            # changing text of label
            self.text_problem.setDisabled(False)
        else:
            # changing text of label
            self.text_problem.setDisabled(True)


# create pyqt5 app
App = QApplication(sys.argv)

# create the instance of our Window
window = Window()

# start the app
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to create hidden labels on your main window that can hold these values. Then just `self.mylabel.setText("myvalue")`. The window must already be initiated/open though.